# Changing C++ compiler version in VS Code not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-c++

I need to use C++17 or higher, however whenever I run a check compiler program it shows that I am using the C++98 version no matter what I change.

I am using MSVC in VS Code for windows 10

```c++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    if (__cplusplus == 202002L) std::cout << "C++20\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 201703L) std::cout << "C++17\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 201402L) std::cout << "C++14\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 201103L) std::cout << "C++11\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 199711L) std::cout << "C++98\n";
    else std::cout << "pre-standard C++\n";
}
```

I changed the c_cpp_properties.json file to C++20 and I changed the settings for Cpp standard in ms-vscode.cpptools to C++20. These are the only two options I have found to solve this online. Please help

Edit: Adding the c_cpp_properties.json to show that I changed it to c++20

```js
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/**"
                
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "8.1",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++20",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

tasks.json

```js
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                "/Zi",
                "/EHsc",
                "/nologo",
                "/Fe${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "${file}",
                "/std=c++20"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

I think I see that the proper version of the compiler will not show unless you use /Zc:__cplusplus or something, but I don't understand what that is and where I should use it.

Comment: I followed the VSCode MSVC instructions, and I thought that was a compiler. Am I just confused?

Comment: Any modern version of msvc should default to c++14

Comment: You need to change `c_cpp_properties.json` for intellisense and the args in `tasks.json` for the compiler depending on how you are building. The msvc vscode documentation is here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc) but it does not describe the compiler arguments. The msvc arguments for that are described in this document: [https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-cpp20-and-the-std-cpp20-switch/](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-cpp20-and-the-std-cpp20-switch/)

Comment: VSCode is a very advanced, complex development tool that's designed for highly skilled, experienced developers who have a wide range of domain knowledge, like the JSON configuration syntax, and familiarity with obscure compiler flags and options. It is not meant to be used for people who are just starting out learning C++ and who do not have established development experience, those people will find other development environments, like VS community edition (Windows) or emacs+make (Linux, MacOS), easier to use.

Comment: The dupes answer your question, which compiler setting you are missing.

Comment: Recommending a modal text editor is a hilariously bad take. And raw make to boot.

Comment: The dupes says you need to also add `/Zc:__cplusplus` to your args for the macro to return the correct answer. ***but I don't understand what that is and where I should use it.*** I believe you want to change `"/std=c++20"`  in your tasks.json to `"/std:c++20",` and put `"/Zc:__cplusplus"` on the next line.